# When "extracting" float value from object of type Object is it better to use cast or .toString method?

Tags: java, casting, floating-point, tostring

I have an object containing float value. I need to "extract" it. Is it better to use cast `float cellValue = (float) b;` or .toString() method `String cellValue = b.toString();`? By better, I mean execution speed, coding practice, memory usage, precision leak. I am going to use that float in prepared statement.

```
            float cellValue = (float) b;
            int cellId = (int) c;               
            String updateString = "update finance.fin " + "set " + colName + "= ? " + "where ID = ? "+ ";";
            prepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(updateString);
            prepStmt.setFloat(1, cellValue);
            prepStmt.setInt(2, cellId);             
            prepStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I think it would be comparing Apples and Oranges. It would depend upon your usage, at end if you want to use as `float` then go for "casting", if you want to use float value as `String` then go for `toString()`. This answers for your "coding practice". And "speed, memory usage, precision leak" are too trivial to consider ..

Answer (score 0):

Its depend on the your scenario.I would say if you are using it for database operation, its depend what you have declared it in database.If its a float you can go with float else String will work as well.(Its regarding coding practice)
About second question , Memory usage and speed , I think you can go with Float only as there is chance of precision leak as well and also if you convert it to String it may impact your application in the case when you want to make some changes to this float value at runtime as String is immutable.